# PostgreSQL - UNION of tables based on number of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, information-schema

I'm working in PostgreSQL, and I want to UNION all tables with 11 columns, of a database called 'postgres'.

The list of the mentioned tables, I get it with the following query.

```
with  
completo_tablas as (
select column_name, table_name from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='public'
)
--,tablas as (
select table_name--, count(column_name)
from completo_tablas
group by table_name
having count(column_name)=11
--)
```

Obteining, something like:

```
Table_name
--------------  
table1  
table2  
.  
.  
.
```

The problem i cant solve, isn't getting the UNION of the tables with 11 columns for a specific day; I know i can do than copying the tables names like:

```
Select * from tabla1 UNION select * from tabla2 UNION Sel....
```

Given the nature of our business, the number of tables is going to increase over time.

What I want, cause of the nature of our business, is a "dynamic" query, where I don't have the names of the tables set by hand in the UNION query.

But something with which you can always get just that, the union of all tables with 11 columns

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What a weird requirement. You could write a function that composes an SQL query with the `UNION`s, then uses `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` to execute it.

Comment: How do you know you can union those tables based on the number of columns? If one table has e.g. a `date` column at the same position where another has e.g. an `int` column, you can still not union them. But even if the data types match, there is no way to do that without dynamic SQL (and thus, a PL/pgSQL function). But this sounds as if you have a serious problem without your data model to be hones

Comment: Absolutely right @a_horse_with_no_name union has 2 conditions to be applied especially, no of columns should be same and data types as well and i think its not about UNION the OP's approach is way different to actual solution

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is a special and specific database that we use only to upload some tables to a external software. Netherless, there are some tables with less than 11 columns, but we are sure that the only tables with 11 columns are all with the same structure.